# REGEX: Getting information from a specific group which is surrounded by many optional groups

Tags: java, regex, capturing-group

Suppose I have a regex expression that matches a string like this:

```
(A)(B)?(C)(D)?(E)(F)?
```

where the groups B, D, and F are optional.

How can I get just group `E`? I ask this because, I don't think I can just call `M.group(5)` because if my matcher `(M)` didn't find groups B and D, then group E is actually group 3 and not group 5.

I did have an idea though.If I did something like:

```
((A)(B)?(C)(D)?)(E)(F)?
```

where A,B,C, and D are all group 1, can I call group 2 to get E?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you *can* just call M.group(5) because the optional capture groups will match null, per this [fiddle](http://fiddle.re/pkh4a).

Comment: Oh, I tried it and it work! I'm just learning regex expressions so I didn't know that -- thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If my answer helped to solve your problem, please consider marking it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). That's the customary way of indicating that your question is "resolved" and thanking the person who helped you.